# What is the best way to find root node of elements DOM (shadow or light)

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I would like to find the DOM scope of given element. In other words document or document fragment that contains it.

Is there anything nicer / faster than than code below?

```
function getRootNode( element ){
  if( document.contains(element) ){
    return document;
  }

  var root = element;
  while( root.parentNode ){
    root = root.parentNode;
  }
  return root;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/rudik/4/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.getRootNode() is the best way to do that in shadow dom it'll return the shadow root otherwise it'll return the document.
See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/getRootNode

Quick note : Currently it's not supported by IE/Edge

Comment: Please add example code in your answer and not just links to external sites.

Comment: Yep sure ! See my CodePen : https://codepen.io/Johann-S/pen/KyEdYW
Based on the code submitted by @tomalec

Answer (score 5):

You can just use [`ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.ownerDocument):

```
element.ownerDocument;
```

Comment: But for not imported, shadow DOM node `element.ownerDocument` returns `document`, not the document fragment/shadowRoot which contains it.

See here: http://jsbin.com/rudik/5/edit